# Is there a document way to create thumbnail from UIImage/UIImageView?

Tags: iphone

I hope to create thumbnail from an UIImage/UIImageView.
There are some undocument solution:
http://ofcodeandmen.poltras.com/2008/10/30/undocumented-uiimage-resizing/
..

I wonder if there is a documented way to create thumbnail from UIImage/UIImageView?

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the `drawInRect` method on the `UIImage`.
I was looking into where I got this approach from and it turns out I originally found it in Apples **LazyTableImages** example.

From the documentation:
*Draws the entire image in the specified rectangle, scaling it as needed to fit*